# “How do you not…”

Tags: colloquial-language

> How do you not doomscroll without turning a blind eye to the injustices happening around the world.

Is the “how do you not” construction awkward/unnatural in a colloquial context?
Also, does the sentence make sense?

[Definition of doomscroll](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/doomsurfing-doomscrolling-words-were-watching)

Comment: It makes no sense to me. What is the meaning of “doomscroll”? The general form of the construction is also odd. “How do you not despair when contemplating the world’s injustice” is common enough. “How do you not despair without the comfort of friends” is also common. But the given sentence baffles me. what is the context?

Comment: [How do you not (do something)?](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22how%20do%20you%20not%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2007,cd_max:2008&lr=lang_en) = How can you avoid (doing something)? How do you not get it? -:)

Comment: @Jeff [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=doomscrolling) can be helpful for Internet terms like this.

Comment: @randomhead Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

As Victor B. commented, "**How do you not [X]?**" is a commonly used construction. The sentence makes sense and sounds perfectly fine to me.